# disable clipboard data past in text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need Some Help I am PHP Developer i want disable auto typing in PHP website means some application

are using clipboard  data direct paste data in  text box, i already disable copy paste using java script and

also disable right click, how to disable auto typing using java script? how to disable clipboard data paste in

my text box ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="q" type="text" id='test' autocomplete="off"/>
```

will turnoff the autocomplete in html . no need of jquery or js

Or if you need it to be done with `javascript`,

```
document.getElementById("test").autocomplete="off"
```